# Is there any way to set mysql's sql_mode in pyspark?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to change `mysql's sql_mode` to `'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'` , when using `pyspark`. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:
   add `&sessionVariables=sql_mode='NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION'` to `jdbc` url.